# Allow to assign only one value between two FK columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, restriction

I tried to find some solution but I couldn't.

Let's supose we have the table bellow and each row of this table needs to be assigned only to one FK (columnfk1  or columnfk2) **(Doesn't make sense be assigned to both OR none)**:

```
CREATE TABLE example(
  id INT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT
  ,name VARCHAR(255)
  ,columnfk1 INT
  ,columnfk2 INT
  ,FOREIGN KEY (columnfk1) REFERENCES example1(columnfk1)
  ,FOREIGN KEY (columnfk2) REFERENCES example2(columnfk2)
);
```

Is there some rule to warrant that each row will have one **FK** assigned?
I'm using MYSQL 5

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support the `check` constraint, because this can easily be handled using such a constraint:

```
check (columnfk1 is null or columnfk2 is null);
```

So, the only way that you can implement this constraint in the database with this data structure is to use a trigger.